# bootstrap 3: pull-right controls inside h3 tag

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I want several controls inside **h3** tag

This is my code:

```
     <h3 >
        <span>header</span>
        <span ng-click="addClientClick()"
              class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus pull-right btn"
              title="Добавить клиента"></span>

        <span class="pull-right">
            <div class="input-group">
                <span  title="Rows per page" class="input-group-addon">
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-th-list"></i>
                </span>
                <select  title="Rows per page" class="form-control "
                         ng-model="pgtr.rowsPerPage.rows" ng-change="pgtr.rowsPerPageChange()"
                         ng-options="rpp for rpp in pgtr.rowsPerPageVariants " >
                </select>
            </div>
        </span>

        <span class="pull-right">
            <ul class="pagination " style="padding: 0 1em 0 1em; margin: 0; ">
                <li >
                    <a href="#" ng-click="pgtr.click('first')">1</a>
                </li>
                <li ng-hide="pgtr.buttons.prev.hide">
                    <a href="#" ng-click="pgtr.click('prev');">2</a>
                </li>
                <li ng-hide="pgtr.buttons.curr.hide" class="active">
                    <a href="#">3</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </span>
    </h3>
```

It's working fine in firefox, but not in Chrome: [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rU6lo.png)

I make [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/sNRWwqul5ennJmJiT8V6?p=preview) for this. Its also working good in firefox, but not correct in chrome.

How I can solve this issue?

Comment: Is there any reason the entire block of HTML code is inside of an `h3` tag? Because honestly, i don't see any reason why you would want that.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using Bootstrap's [grid system](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid). This should keep the html elements in the right place depending on the screen width (also mobile screens)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>

  <body>
    <h3>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-4">
        <span>header</span>
        <span ng-click="addClientClick()" class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus pull-right btn" title="Добавить клиента"></span>
      </div>
  
      <div class="col-xs-4">
        <span class="pull-right">
            <div class="input-group">
              <span  title="Rows per page" class="input-group-addon">
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-th-list"></i>
              </span>
              <select title="Rows per page" class="form-control " ng-model="pgtr.rowsPerPage.rows" ng-change="pgtr.rowsPerPageChange()" ng-options="rpp for rpp in pgtr.rowsPerPageVariants ">
              </select>
            </div>
      </span>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-4">
        <span class="pull-right">
          <ul class="pagination " style="padding: 0 1em 0 1em; margin: 0; ">
                      <li >
                          <a href="#" ng-click="pgtr.click('first')">1</a>
                      </li>
                      <li ng-hide="pgtr.buttons.prev.hide">
                          <a href="#" ng-click="pgtr.click('prev');">2</a>
                      </li>
                      <li ng-hide="pgtr.buttons.curr.hide" class="active">
                          <a href="#">3</a>
                      </li>
          </ul>
        </span>
      </div>
    </div>
    </h3>
  </body>
</html>
```

Play with the column sizing (col-sx-**) until you are satisfied.

Comment: Thanks, I will try it.